# Can I set up Kate to always fold (collapse) all foldable regions when opening a code file?

Tags: kate

I'd like to set up Kate so that, if I open, for example, a C++ file, all classes it contains are folded? But not only the root levels, when I unfold a class, I'd like methods inside it to be initially folded too. Etc. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm seeing, you won't be able to achieve this without modifying the kate's code. I would suggest putting in a formal feature request (a wish) on their [tracking system](https://bugs.kde.org/buglist.cgi?product=kate&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_severity=wishlist).

It's a feature that I would want as well :)